# create a record in a different class(table)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class People and class User (from Devise).
When someone signs up a user row(object) gets created in the User class(table).
I would also like the user.rb model to create a row(object) in the People class(table).
(The user.rb also has "has_one :person" in it.)

I tried the following without success:

```
after_create :create_person

protected
def create_person
  self.create_person email: self.email
end
```

How could I code this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
after_create :create_person

protected
def create_person
 Person.create(self.attributes)
end
```

But take care, if you want to update the person record when the corresponding user record is updated use `after_save` and `Person.find_or_create_by_email(self.email)`

Comment: Can I set just one attribute in the new Person (email).  Right now I get "unknown attribute: encrypted_password".

Comment: Yup, sure, try Person.create(:email => self.email)

Answer (score 0):

The code you show should work,
the only reason why it might not work would be validations.

Doing `create_person` will do a `save` not a `save!`.

If you have validation on the `Person` model, it may be failing.